# SF story with a talking bull getting even during a bullfight

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, animals

Probably written in the 1940s or 1950s, this story featured an intelligent talking bull who asked to be entered into a bullfight to get revenge on the cruel humans who killed his brethren.

The story had a post-apocalyptic feeling to it, but that was mostly in the background. There was something in it about atomic bomb testing.

I think there was also a duel between the bull's owner and some yahoo, but I don't remember that as clearly. Animals turning the tables on humans is what stuck with me.

Comment: If you enjoyed this one, you might like "[The bull that thought](http://www.telelib.com/authors/K/KiplingRudyard/prose/DebtsandCredits/bullthought.html)" by Rudyard Kipling. Quite a similar theme.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is Robert Ernest Gilbert's (1953) "[Thy Rocks and Rills](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/32878/32878-h/32878-h.htm)".

**An intelligent (talking) bull is spoiling for a bullfight.**

> Stonecypher concealed spear and dummy beneath the floor of the dog
>   house. Going to the paddock, he patted the bull between the horns,
>   which had been filed to a needle point. "Still goin' through with it?"
>   Stonecypher asked.
>
> "Yaaaa," the bull lowed. "Yaooo kuhl Daan. Err'll kuhl uhhh kuhlerrs."

**His intelligence was the result of atomic bombs and mutations**

> "The scientists got real excited when they heard about it, 'cause they
>   wanted to see how horrible they could make Atomic Bomb. So, they
>   shipped fifty-nine cattle up to Oak Ridge. That was a Government town,
>   a hundred miles southwest of here, where they made some of the stuff
>   to put in Atomic Bomb. The University of Tennessee was runnin' an
>   experimental farm there. They had donkeys, and pigs, and chickens, and
>   other animals that they exposed to radioactivity. Then they killed 'em
>   and cut 'em up to see what had happened. I know it's gruesome, but
>   that's how it was.

Comment: I just skimmed it and that's it. There's also a lot more to it than I remembered. You rock!

Comment: @rosesunhill - Ah well, [modesty forbids me from answering...](http://tinyurl.com/or8srdd)